# RestKit JSON mapping when CoreData entity is part of JSON collection

Tags: json, core-data, restkit

I imagine there must me a solution for this, I haven't found one however.

I receive JSON responses of this structure:

```
{
    description: SomeString,
    type: ACTIVITY,
    timestamp: 1224043200000,
    creationTime: 1224043200000,
    userIdentification: 1111-2222-3333,
    value: 2000
}
```

"Activity" is the name of my CoreData entity. How do I map this JSON to my data model? All examples I found so far assume a JSON similar to this format:

```
{
    activity: {
        description: SomeString,
        timestamp: 1224043200000,
        creationTime: 1224043200000,
        userIdentification: 1111-2222-3333,
        value: 2000
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have multiple possible different `type`s, each with an associated entity...

Define a mapping for each entity. Don't connect these directly to the response descriptors. Instead, create an [`RKDynamicMapping`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKDynamicMapping.html#//api/name/addMatcher%3a) instance with a block (`setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:`, or a matcher) which checks the `type` of the data coming in and returns the appropriate mapping.

If your responses contain multiple different `type`s in a single response then you may want to look at combining the above with KVC validation to reject any objects created with the wrong type. You would also need some different response descriptors or something to apply each of the different entity mappings...

Comment: This looks just like what I need. I will have a look if `RKDynamicMapping` solves my issue and come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can look in the ObjectMapping section of the RestKit repo on github. To map your json response you can make use of the nil keyPath as explained here https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#mapping-values-without-key-paths.

As Wain said, you should use Dynamic Mapping to decide which class will be mapped with the json object that you are receiving depending on the value that certain attribute have. How to use Dynamic Mapping is explained here: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#dynamic-object-mapping. I know it's late, but this could help somebody in the future.